# switch meshes between two hierarchy in blender respecting all the animations?

Tags: edit-mode

I have two files with similar hierarchy only difference is they visually look different, file1 has animations, now what i want to achieve is update the hair mesh on file1 with hair mesh from file2 and so file1 scene can play animations with new updated hair, how move file1 hair hierarchy to hierarchy of file1 so the newly added mesh(hair) participates in animations from file1.

Comment: Hello, it's best if you don't rely on users downloading random files on the internet. Could you add more information in textual form or using screenshots of your interface ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: yes, please check the update, is it understandable enough?

Comment: Ive changed then question again, please check